# how do understand word "for" in the phrase "black women for wellness"

Tags: word-meaning

A NGO named black women for wellness, its website [black women for wellness](http://www.bwwla.org/). what does this phrase mean? black women who pursue wellness, or healthy black women, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, *for* has the meaning along the lines of

> [for](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/for)
>   7 used for saying who or what you support or prefer
>   a. used for saying which person or thing someone supports or agrees with

So I understood it as *Black women in support of wellness*.

On their site, the tag line is

> Committed to Healing, Educating, and Supporting Black Women!

It is implied that it is *black women* committed to healing, educating, and supporting black women.

Answer (score -1):

`group` for `cause that they support`

Examples:

`Citizens` for `a sound economy`

`Black women` for `wellness`

`Campaign` for `nuclear disarmament`

`People` for `the ethical treatment of animals`

Disclaimer all examples were taken based on how easy there were found. They do not necessarily represent my views. Hah.